# tinyMCE (jquery version) grayed out and not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tinymce

I am working on expanding a home-made CMS. This CMS relies on jquery and jqueryUI for the most part. I was trying to switch from my home made and some how limited WYSIWYG editor to the very powerfull tinyMCE.
I've worked with tinyMCE previously on standard website and worked flawlessly.

Just a bit of background: my CMS works has a GUI that could remind you of "photoshop" or something alike. By saying that I mean that one huge windows loads and every "subpage" opens withing a new "window" (a div) loaded via AJAX.

I've setup all tinyMCE references and everything 'should' be working fine but it is not :
When I load this "window" containing tinyMCE, I have my textarea replaced with the tinyMCE UI, but the area where I am suppose to be able to edit/write, is just grayed out and I cant edit anything.

The code itself is pretty straight forward:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
mode : "textareas",
theme : "advanced"
});
</script>
<textarea id="myText" name="myText"></textarea>
```

(I can't send image: new user... But you can take a look at: http://www.iroure.com/tinymce.jpg).

As you can see in the screenshot, the grayed area (marked 'Not Working'), shouldn't be gray, should be white and should work...
Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Any errors in the console? I think i had similar problem a while ago, but i just can't recall what was a problem.